# Allow an enemy to follow the player

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to get an enemy, called fudd_img, to follow the player who is playing as bear_img. fudd_img should be slower than the player themselves.

I have tried using the lines:

```
if bear_rect_x > fudd_rect_x:
    fudd_rect_x = fudd_rect_x + max(2, bear_rectx - fudd_rect_x)
elif bear_rect_x < fudd_rect_x:
    fudd_rect_x = fudd_rect_x - max(2, fudd_rect_x - bear_rect_x)
```

but instead, fudd_img will act exactly as bear_img instead of finding a path to the bear_img. Whenever I try to translate this to y, it doesn't work and fudd_img will not move along the y axis.

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

GREEN = (24, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480
SW2 = SCREEN_WIDTH/2
SH2 = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2

#---
camerax = 0
cameray = 0
# --- functions ---

def text_objects(text, font):
    surface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return surface, surface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    surface, rect = text_objects(text, CLOCKTXT)
    rect.center = (58, 15)
    screen.blit(surface, rect)
    #pygame.display.update() # use update() only in one place

#generate random pos for fish and grass
def getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, objWidth, objHeight):
    camera_rect = pygame.Rect(camerax, cameray, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    x1 = camerax - SCREEN_WIDTH
    x2 = camerax + (2*SCREEN_WIDTH)
    y1 = cameray - SCREEN_HEIGHT
    y2 = cameray + (2*SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    while True:
        x = random.randint(x1, x2)
        y = random.randint(y1, y2)
        obj_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, objWidth, objHeight)
        if not obj_rect.colliderect(camera_rect):
            return x, y

def makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray):
    w, h = 80, 80
    x, y = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, w, h)
    images = grasspic
    item = {
        'image': random.choice(images),
        'rect': pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h),
    }
    return item

def makeNewFish(camerax, cameray):
    w, h = 50, 50
    x, y = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, w, h)
    images = fishpic
    item = {
        'image': random.choice(images),
        'rect': pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h),
    }
    return item

def makegrass(number=15):    
    for i in range(number):
        item = makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray)
        item['rect'].x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH-item['rect'].width)
        item['rect'].y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-item['rect'].height)
        allgrass.append(item)

def makefish(number=2):
    for i in range(number):
        item = makeNewFish(camerax, cameray)
        item['rect'].x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH-item['rect'].width)
        item['rect'].y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-item['rect'].height)
        allfish.append(item)

def score_draw(score):
    message_display("Score is: " + str(score))

#--- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hungry Boi') 

CLOCKTXT = pygame.font.Font('freesans.ttf', 20)

# ---

bear_img = pygame.image.load('bear.png')
bear_img = pygame.transform.scale(bear_img, (150, 150))
bear_rect = bear_img.get_rect()
bear_rect.x = SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.4
bear_rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.4
bear_vel = 5

fudd_img = pygame.image.load('fudd.png')
fudd_img = pygame.transform.scale(fudd_img, (150,150))
fudd_rect = fudd_img.get_rect()
fudd_rect.x = SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.4
fudd_rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.4
fudd_vel = 2

grasspic = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    image = pygame.image.load('grass%s.png' % i)
    grasspic.append(image)

fishpic = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    image = pygame.image.load('fish%s.png' % i)
    image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (50, 50))
    fishpic.append(image)

# ---

allgrass = []
makegrass()

allfish = []
makefish()

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

score = 0
time = 60

# --- mainloop ---

gameExit = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not gameExit:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change -= bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change -= bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change += bear_vel

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change += bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change -= bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change += bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change -= bear_vel

    # --- updates ---

    bear_rect.x += x_change
    bear_rect.y += y_change

    keep_fish = []
    for fish in allfish:
        if not bear_rect.colliderect(fish['rect']):
            keep_fish.append(fish)
        else:
            makefish(1)
            #makegrass()
            score += 1
    allfish = keep_fish

    # --- time down ---
    for i in range(60):
        time -= 1

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(GREEN)

    for grass in allgrass:
        screen.blit(grass['image'], grass['rect'].move(camerax, cameray))

    for fish in allfish:
        screen.blit(fish['image'], fish['rect'].move(camerax, cameray))

    screen.blit(bear_img, bear_rect.move(camerax, cameray))
    screen.blit(fudd_img, fudd_rect.move(camerax, cameray))
    score_draw(score)


    pygame.display.update()

    # --- FPS ---

    clock.tick(30) #fps//may not be safe to run really fast

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

How do I get fudd_img to follow the player, bear_img but not layer on top of the player and spawn on the top left corner of the game? I am hoping that later, this will make it easier for a collision system to work.

Thank you

Comment: Please share what you've already tried.

Comment: And how do you want the enemy to follow? Should he take the exact same path the player has taken or should he find his own shortest path to the player?

Comment: @embie27 find the shortest path to the player

Comment: You need to have a look into pathfinding, then. Just ask your favourite search engine about this topic, there are several algorithms. I don't know which one fits your application best.

Comment: if it follows in a straight line without any obstacles then you can use [pygame.math.Vector2D.angle_to](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to) to find angle between player and enemy and use it to calculate `move_x, move_y` for enemy.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to follow in a straight line without any obstacles then you can use pygame.math.Vector2D to make all calculations. It has all needed functions to make it simpler and it uses `float` values so move can be smoother.

First I convert positions from `pygame.Rect` to `pygame.math.Vector2D`

```
player_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(player_rect.center)
enemy_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(enemy_rect.center)
```

next I calculate difference between both objects (it still gives vector)

```
diff = player_vector - enemy_vector
```

If I add it to enemy's position then it gets player's position - enemy would get player in one step but I need shorter vector with the same direction to move enemy slower - to move it in more steps.

If I normalize vector then I get vector with the same direction but shorter. It's length is 1.

```
move = diff.normalize()
```

Now I can add it to enemy's position to make small step in player's direction.

```
enemy_vector += move
```

And now I can use new position to convert back to position in pygame.Rect

```
enemy_rect.center = enemy_vector
```

and draw on screen

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, player_rect)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, enemy_rect)
```

If I want to faster move then I can multiplicate normalized vector

```
move = diff.normalize() * 2
```

---

```
player_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(player_rect.center)
enemy_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(enemy_rect.center)

diff = player_vector - enemy_vector

move = diff.normalize() * 2
enemy_vector += move

enemy_rect.center = enemy_vector

pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, player_rect)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, enemy_rect)
```

---

To make move smoother I will keep enemy's position in Vector (as float values) and convert to pygame.Rect only to draw it.

Full working example. Player is in center, enemy starts in random position and move to player. It displays also line between objects. You can move player using arrows.

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

SCREEN_WIDTH_HALF = SCREEN_WIDTH//2
SCREEN_HEIGHT_HALF = SCREEN_HEIGHT//2

#--- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

player_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 16, 16)
player_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH_HALF, SCREEN_HEIGHT_HALF)
player_speed = 2

enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 16, 16)
enemy_rect.centerx = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH)
enemy_rect.centery = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
enemy_speed = 2

enemy_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(enemy_rect.center)

#old_rect = enemy_rect.copy()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(15) # 120 FPS
    #pygame.time.delay(5)

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # --- changes ---

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # move player

    if player_rect.top > 0 and keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player_rect.y -= player_speed
    if player_rect.bottom < SCREEN_HEIGHT and keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player_rect.y += player_speed

    if player_rect.left > 0 and keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_rect.x -= player_speed
    if player_rect.right < SCREEN_WIDTH and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player_rect.x += player_speed

    # enemy follow player

    player_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(player_rect.center)
    diff = player_vector - enemy_vector
    if diff.length() > 0.1:
        move = diff.normalize() * enemy_speed
        enemy_vector += move
        enemy_rect.center = enemy_vector

    # -- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, player_rect.center, enemy_rect.center)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, player_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, enemy_rect)
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, old_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```